# What does this block of Scala code mean

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

Hi i am relatively new to Scala, i would like to try this Play 2 Framework and stuck with the following code (used as a template)

```
<article  class="tasks">
        @todoTasks.groupBy(_.project).map {
            case (project, tasks) => {
                <div class="folder" data-folder-id="@project.id">
                    <header>
                        <h3>@project.name</h3>
                    </header>
                    <ul class="list">
                        @tasks.map { task =>
                            <li data-task-id="@task.id">
                                <h4>@task.title</h4>
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            }
        }
    </article>
```

What does this line mean?

```
@todoTasks.groupBy(_.project).map {
```

and how do you use scala *.map in the context of Play 2 Framework.

I'd appreciate it if you could explain it in exact detail as i am relatively new to Scala (coming from Java developer)

Answer (score 4):

`groupBy()` applies the given lambda expression (`_.project`, which extracts `project` from a task) to each element of the collection, and groups elements by results of that expression.

So, it converts a list of tasks into a list of tuples `(project, tasksOfThatProject)`.

Now, `map()` applies its lambda expression to each element of the collection (i.e. to each of these tuples).

Lambda expression given to `map()` renders a tuple as project name and a list of its tasks.

Comment: is this Lambda expression similar to lambda function you would found in Python? Anyway, thanks for the explanation. I am trying to digest it now.